# Softmax MLP Classifier - which activation function to use in hidden layer?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, softmax, activation-function

I am writing a single Multi-Layer Perceptron from scratch, with just an input, hidden and output layer. The output layer will use the softmax activation function to produce probabilities of several mutually exclusive outputs.

In my hidden layer it does not make sense to me to use the softmax activation function too - is this correct? If so can I just use any other non-linear activation function such as sigmoid or tanh? Or could I even not use any activation function in the hidden layer and just keep the values of the hidden nodes as the linear combinations of the input nodes and input-to-hidden weights?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In my hidden layer it does not make sense to me to use the softmax activation function too - is this correct?

It is correct indeed.

> If so can I just use any other non-linear activation function such as sigmoid or tanh?

You can, but most modern approaches would call for a [Rectified Linear Unit (ReLU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifier_(neural_networks)), or some of its variants (Leaky ReLU, ELU etc).

> Or could I even not use any activation function in the hidden layer and just keep the values of the hidden nodes as the linear combinations of the input nodes and input-to-hidden weights?

No. The non-linear activations are indeed what prevents a (possibly large) neural network from behaving just like a single linear unit; it can be shown (see Andrew Ng's relevant lecture @ Coursera [Why do you need non-linear activation functions?](https://www.coursera.org/learn/neural-networks-deep-learning/lecture/OASKH/why-do-you-need-non-linear-activation-functions)) that:

> It turns out that if you use
>    a linear activation function, or
>    alternatively if you don't have an
>    activation function, then no matter how
>    many layers your neural network has,
>    what is always doing is just computing a linear
>    activation function, so you might as well
>    not have any hidden layers.
>
> The
>    take-home is that a linear hidden layer
>    is more or less useless because the
>    composition of two linear functions is
>    itself a linear function; so unless you
>    throw a non-linearity in there then
>    you're not computing more interesting
>    functions even as you go deeper in the
>    network.

Practically, the only place where you could use a linear activation function is the output layer for *regression* problems (explained also in the lecture linked above).

Answer (score 1):

You can use any activation function. Just test some and go for the one yielding the best results. Don't forget to try Relu though. That is as far as I know the simplest which actually works very well.

Comment: Too vague; "any activation function" for the hidden layers (which is what OP asks) may include softmax (not advisable) and linear (plain wrong) activations